# ValueError from Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm having an issue with a program I wrote, it runs for some iterations then eventually stops and gives me the error `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`. I tried to look for a similar problem but could not find any suggestion on how to fix it. Here is the code I'm working with.

```
def process_teams(driver, club_):
    #print('Processing for ',club_)
    
    oppL = list()
    timL = list()
    timFL = list()
    opFL = list()
    
    try:
        i_ = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("More")
        i_[2].click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        tr_s = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr")
    except(IndexError):
        return oppL, timL
    
    knt = 0
    
    
    
    for _ in tr_s:
        try:
            #knt += 1
            tmCnr = 0
            opCnr = 0
            tfF = 0
            opF = 0
            
            var1 = _.find_element_by_xpath("td[6]/a")
            tst = var1.text.strip()
            ba_ = tst.split('-')
            if len(ba_)<2:
                pass
            else:
                #print('-----------------------------------------------')
                #knt += 1    # knt is number of games to be processed
                var1.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
                
                # Now consider different tabs
                cur_tab = driver.current_window_handle
                
                # Assuming our newly opened Tab is the list in list of handles
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                
                var2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr")
                #print('Length: ',len(var2))
                if len(var2) > 6:
                    var3 = var2[2].find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
                    var4 = var2[0].find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
                    var5 = var2[3].find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
                    t__ = var4[0].text.strip()
                    
                    if var3[1].text.strip() == 'Corners':
                        knt += 1
                        if t__ == club_:
                            tmCnr = var3[0].text.strip()
                            opCnr = var3[2].text.strip()
                        else:
                            opCnr = var3[0].text.strip()
                            tmCnr = var3[2].text.strip()
                        timL.append(int(tmCnr))
                        oppL.append(int(opCnr))

                    if var5[1].text.strip() == 'Corners (Half)':
                        #print('First half corners included')
                        if t__ == club_:
                            tfF = var5[0].text.strip()
                            opF = var5[2].text.strip()
                        else:
                            opF = var5[0].text.strip()
                            tfF = var5[2].text.strip()

                        timFL.append(int(tfF))
                        opFL.append(int(opF))
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to.window(cur_tab)
            
            if knt > 4:     # Stops running when we discover knt > 5 (i.e 5 games processed so far)
                break
        except(NoSuchElementException):
            pass
        except(IndexError):
            pass
        
    return timL, oppL, timFL, opFL
```

And this is how I make the call to the function `hmL, atL, hmFL, atFL = process_teams(driver, home)`. I just don't understand why the program will run smoothly for some iterations then throw the error, and not at the very beginning, any suggestions on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might have something to do with how many variables you are returning.  At the first `try except` block you return 2 variables, but at the end of your code you return 4 variables. Perhaps try returning the other 2 empty lists as well (in the first `try except` block) so that you return the same amount of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you return 2 variables

```
   except(IndexError):
        return oppL, timL
```

Sometimes you return 4.

```
  return timL, oppL, timFL, opFL
```

I guess you're getting the error when it throws an IndexError